# Java Code Compatability issue (my binary is also not working)

Tags: java, swing, sqlite, miglayout

I have written a Java application using Eclipse Juno on Fedora 17. I have JRE 1.7 installed, but I changed the Java build path to 1.6, I believe. Everything works fine there. I can then build a .jar file which runs on a Windows 7 virtual machine without problems. However, if I try to run it on the school computers (Windows 7 
`java version "1.6.0_18"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_18-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 16.0-b13, mixed mode, sharing)`)

it gives an exception like: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot add to layout: constraint must be a string`. This is apparently something to do with CardLayout, which I believe is a standard Swing component.

I am using [miglayout](http://miglayout.com) library and [sqlite-jdbc driver](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-jdbc/) if that could be related.

I would really appreciate help with this

Comment: Try to compile with the JDK 6.

Comment: @Thilo not with JDK 6 but using the `--target`-flag with the compiler.

Comment: No, try to compile with the JDK 6. --target --source are insufficient (they just specify bytecode and sourcecode levels), you also need the proper runtime libraries (to check which API existed back then). Hard to get right. Safest to compile with JDK 6.

Comment: Is there some way to do this with eclipse since it handles the compiler

Comment: You are using MigLayout but you say that it'is related with CardLayout. Could you give more details ?

Comment: @gontard I only say that because miglayout uses strings to setup components and the error is something to do with strings

Comment: My question is why do you writes this : "This is apparently something to do with CardLayout" ? why assume that ?

Comment: @gontard Well that's where the exception apparently occurs.

Comment: It is difficult to help you without an [sscce](http://sscce.org/)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

cardLayoutPanel is a JPanel
cardLayout is obvious
identifier is a String

```
cardLayoutPanel.add(container);
cardLayout.addLayoutComponent(container, identifier);
```

turns out that in Java 1.6 this doesn't really work because it should actually be:

```
cardLayoutPanel.add(container, identifier);
```

without the second line
Java 1.7 doesn't complain for some reason. Weird.